# specifying a cin value (c++)

Tags: c++, int, cout

say I have:

```
int lol;
cout << "enter a number(int): ";
cin >> lol
cout << lol;
```

If I type 5 then it'll cout 5. If I type fd it couts some numbers.
How can I specify the value, like say I only want it an int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type in `fd` it will output some numbers because those numbers are what `lol` happens to have in them before it gets assigned to. The `cin >> lol` doesn't write to `lol` because it has no acceptable input to put in it, so it just leaves it alone and the value is whatever it was before the call. Then you output it (which is UB).

If you want to make sure that the user entered something acceptable, you can wrap the `>>` in an `if`:

```
if (!(cin >> lol)) {
    cout << "You entered some stupid input" << endl;
}
```

Also you might want to assign to `lol` before reading it in so that if the read fails, it still has some acceptable value (and is not UB to use):

```
int lol = -1; // -1 for example
```

If, for example, you want to loop until the user gives you some valid input, you can do

```
int lol = 0;

cout << "enter a number(int): ";

while (!(cin >> lol)) {
    cout << "You entered invalid input." << endl << "enter a number(int): ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

// the above will loop until the user entered an integer
// and when this point is reached, lol will be the input number
```

Comment: i dunno why but it still couts random number when i input something thats not a number, why is this?

Comment: @BartekSowka because of what I said. `lol` has some uninitialised value and it _does not get changed_ if the user inputs something that isn't a number. The `if` will tell you if `lol` was changed. You have to _not output `lol`_ if the user inputted something that is not a number.

Comment: @BartekSowka see the update in my answer above for an example.

Comment: I don't want to sound disrespectful and sorry if I say something that will offend you (I'm not that eloquent you see). I can't really understand you. I did find one solution that I don't know what to do at the start of the code, I could set a string and then check if the input has letters, if it does then it will print the string, if it doesn't then it'll print the actual int.

Comment: @BartekSowka did you try my example?

Comment: The edited version works but when I enter a string it keeps on saying You entered invalid input, its in a loop i guess.

Comment: FIXED IT. turns out i did it the wrong way round + i changed while to if. EDIT: turns out the else was messin it up, i just added another if after that and it worked :D thanks again.